# Ошибка в коде C/C++

Tags: router, c, tftp, c++

Есть исходник специализированной tftp утилиты для  busybox роутера (весь текст не привожу, дабы не утомлять народ копипастом)вот фрагмент:

```
#if !defined(SUPPORT_SQN_KTHP)  
    if ((cmd == 0) || (optind == argc) || !(glbUploadType == 'i' || glbUploadType == 'c' || glbUploadType == 'f')) {
        bb_show_usage();
    }
#else
    if ((cmd == 0) || (optind == argc) || !(glbUploadType == 's' || glbUploadType == 'd' || glbUploadType == 'p'|| glbUploadType == 'k' || glbUploadType == 'i')) {
        bb_show_usage();
    }
#endif

    if(!remotefile || remotefile[0] == '\0')
        bb_show_usage();

    if (glbUploadType == 'i' && cmd != tftp_cmd_get){
        printf("tftp client only support upgrade firmware\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ( glbUploadType == 's' || glbUploadType == 'd' || glbUploadType == 'p'|| glbUploadType == 'k' ){
        if ( !(andyCheckTftpcEnable()) ){
            printf("Can not enable upgrade/download certificate data\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (glbUploadType == 'c')
        fBufType = BUF_CONFIG_DATA;
```

Теоретически в итоге должна быть проверка возможности загрузки/выгрузки соотв.файлов по tftp.Если не сходится - вывод соотв.команды: "Can not enable upgrade/download certificate data".
 После сборки help tftp пишет

```
Usage: tftp [OPTION]... tftp_server_ip

Update certificate data from/or backup certificate.
data to a tftp server.
Options:
-g      Get file. (Certificate data)
-p      Put file. (backup Certificate data)
-f      remote file name.
-t      s for server root ,d for device, p for device private and k
```

Ввожу команду:
**tftp –g 192.168.1.2 –f file.pem –ts** (аналогичная команда на загрузку образа прошивки - работает - 
*tftp –g 192.168.1.2 –f file.bin –ti*)
в результате получаю **"Can not enable upgrade/download certificate data"**  Причем неважно *–g* или *–p* 
Догадываюсь, что ошибка вот здесь:

```
if ( glbUploadType == 's' || glbUploadType == 'd' || glbUploadType == 'p'|| glbUploadType == 'k' ){
            if ( !(andyCheckTftpcEnable()) ){
                printf("Can not enable upgrade/download certificate data\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
```

Подскажите, плз, что надо исправить, если я прав

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что исправлять? andyCheckTftpcEnable() возвращает false в случае -ts. В случае ti этот код не отрабатывает. Смотрите andyCheckTftpcEnable().

Comment: @andruxa Спасибо за оперативный ответ. Проблема была в том, что "andyCheckTftpcEnable" отвергает опции, определяющие тип передаваемого файла. Далее они используются для загрузки/копирования соотв. файлов, но действие прерывается раньше. Пробую разобраться с "andy..."  и с опциями. Результат отпишу

Answer (score 1):

Код был правильный проверил связные файлы - функция "andyCheckTftpcEnable" по умолчанию проверяет включен ли телнет и если нет - создается сокет, но в правилах поддержка телнета не была указана. Необходимо было добавить в начало файла (правила)

```
 #define SUPPORT_ENABLE_TELNET
```

и все заработало правильно